# QT macro Q_SLOTS after the class access restriction

Tags: c++, qt, macros

I am reading the rviz source code. I found the macro Q_SLOTS after the protected. I am not sure the meaning here. (I understand the access restriction to the class members 'proected' meaning).

```
  class _RosTopicDisplay: public Display
        {
                        Q_OBJECT
                public:
                        _RosTopicDisplay()
                        {
                                topic_property_ = new RosTopicProperty("Topic", "",
                                                                       "", "",
                                                                       this, SLOT(updateTopic()));
                                unreliable_property_ = new BoolProperty("Unreliable", false,
                                                                        "Prefer UDP topic transport",
                                                                        this,
                                                                        SLOT(updateTopic()));
                        }

                protected Q_SLOTS:
                        virtual void updateTopic() = 0;

                protected:
                        RosTopicProperty* topic_property_;
                        BoolProperty* unreliable_property_;
        };
```

Anyone could explain it for me plz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Q_SLOTS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#Q_SLOT)
>
> Use this macro to replace the slots keyword in class declarations,
>   when you want to use Qt Signals and Slots with a 3rd party signal/slot
>   mechanism.
>
> The macro is normally used when no_keywords is specified with the
>   CONFIG variable in the .pro file, but it can be used even when
>   no_keywords is not specified.

It is basically a safer version of `slots`, which is a likely identifier to be used by some other library. As for the access specifier - that is supported for slots too, the same rules apply as for regular methods, with the exception that IIRC you could bypass restricted access and invoke such slots through the meta system.